# Why is my website not recognising classes?

Tags: class, html, fonts, styles

I'm learning to use html. I want the words 'hello welcome to my blog' to appear in courier font. But I want to set it up as a 'class'.

I'm on blogger and I can't seem to get the code working to make this text appear. I'm sure I typed out everything right but for some reason blogspot won't apply the courier font.

However it can read things like h1/h2/Bold/Italic but only when this is directly written before class not in brackets on its own.

```
<head>
<style>
.font (font-family:courier;)
</ style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="font">
Hello welcome to my blog </div>
</ body>
```

Comment: check the update of my answer

Answer (score 2):

In CSS syntax you need to wrap **properties** and **values** within braces `{}` not in parenthesis `()`

Also you need to close the tags carefully like this `</body>` Don't use space inside like this `</ body>`

So you code should look like this-

```
<head>
    <style>
        .font {
            font-family:courier;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="font">
    Hello welcome to my blog
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `()` with `{}` on the style

```
<html>
<head>
<STYLE type=" text/css ">
.font{font-family :"Courier New", Courier, monospace}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="font">
`Hello welcome to my blog</div> </body>
</html>
```

[demo for this](http://jsfiddle.net/k3rnel31/pWpTR/1/)